Cloudflare Pages deployment with webpack and yarn
I'm seeing a 404 error on Cloudflare after "successfully" deploying my React/webpack application to Pages. I suspect it has something to do with setting my entrypoint, but have had no success correcting it. Everything works locally of course, both development and production builds.
Here's the source code for my application, and here's the deployment.
The build command is yarn build:prod or cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider webpack --mode production --config ./webpack/webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile, and the build output directory is /dist. All the expected contents of /dist end up in the "Assets Uploaded" column of the deployment details, and nothing more:

server.js
server.js.LICENSE.txt
stats.json

I've attached my production domain to the service as well, if that affects anything, but the 404 issue existed before this.
Some insight would be truly helpful, either about this specific problem or about what sort of structure I should be expecting in a working deployment.
I've tried moving index.html into the root, and targeting it as the entrypoint using main in package.json. I've also tried setting main to match the webpack.config entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './src/client.js'], and tried setting it to ./dist/server.js. I've also tried a couple different build output directories on the cloudflare end.
